# I created an adaptive layout, it's working fine but i know it's not very good, So, need a better solution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

One I created is petty much adaptive but for performance reasons, I don't find it very useful. I added some empty linear layouts with weights to add adaptive margins on Top, left, right, middle, and bottom. But I think there might be other solutions to get rid of those empty layouts, considering layout to be adaptive. Thanks in advance :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".StacksGameActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_n" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@color/royal_blue_color">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

I attached an image explaining this layout [image: here]
Please suggest me if I can use anything else to make it look like this layout without adding those empty layouts

Comment: have you done some research on other android layouts ? anything particular that you're struggling with? you haven't really explained what your problem is, you just want different solutions here :)

Comment: What i want is,  To optimize my layout for performance reasons taking in consideration adptiveness of layout to different screen sizes. This one is adaptive but it can result i think there must be some solutions out there to remove those empty layouts

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) to get rid of this empty LinearLayouts which might have an impact in performance.

You could set an integer in resources:

```
<integer name="grid_column_count">1</integer>
```

And retrieve it in the code:

```java
int gridColumnCount = 
        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);
```

And use it:

```java
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
                     GridLayoutManager(this, gridColumnCount));
```

Set your items centered and then just set different values for the integer `grid_column_count` depending on the device width by placing its value in different resource directories.

This way you won't use empty linear layouts and will achieve the same look and feel with different number of columns depending on the device width.

You can see a complete example of this in the [Android fundamentals 05.3: Adaptive layouts](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-adaptive-layouts/) codelab.